# How to move manually versioned files to git (version control)?

Tags: git, version-control

I am preparing to move the source code of my project to Git. Up to now, I haven't used any version-control system to keep track of the changes, but I maintained successive versions of files by appending the date. For instance, for a file called "myfile", I would keep copies such as `myfile-d20130629`, `myfile-d20140223`, `myfile-d20141019`, etc. 
A copy called `myfile` (without date) would correspond to the latest version.

Is there a way (using Git or other means) to populate the history of a brand new repository with commits corresponding to those past versions? In other words, the history of such a repo would contain commit `d20130629`, commit `d20140223` commit `d20141019`.

Moreover, is it possible to add the correct (past) date in each one of these commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can use the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

git init

for i in $(ls -1tr)
do
    cp "$i" myfile
    git add myfile
    COMMIT_MESSAGE=$(echo "$i" | cut -d '-' -f2)
    COMMIT_DATE=$(echo "$COMMIT_MESSAGE" | sed -E 's,([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}),\1.\2.\3,g')
    echo $COMMIT_DATE
    git commit -m $COMMIT_MESSAGE --date=$COMMIT_DATE
done
```

Keep in mind that `ls` output should not be parsed in more serious scripts and that it will work here only if files can be sorted in the correct order by their modification date.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. The requirement is to add old versions (myfile-d*) of myfile under that name (myfile) and not as separate new git files. Last version of file myfile is already added. So, even if we replace `git add "$i"` with `git add myfile` I don't know if that makes sense ...

Comment: Thank you  for your script that can  perfectly do the job!

Comment: Thank you for being  so kind to answer to my question by giving such a detailed solution.

Comment: I would expect that version control systems like git,  to address such an issue in a more typical manner. I think that there is a lot of people that plans to move to version control that may use such a manual way to keep old versions.  Does anybody knows if there is any typical git procedure to load/import old versions?